# Casting each element of tensorflow tensor to tuple using tf.map_fn

Tags: tensorflow

I have this piece of code:

```
import Tensorflow as tf
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(['()', '(2,3)', '(4)'])
```

I want to convert that tensor to get a list of tuples `[(), (2,3), (4)]` in the form of tensor.

How can I do that using `tf.map_fn`?
I tried this `tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: tuple(t), elems=a)`

but it threw error:
`TypeError: Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor.`

Thanks!

Comment: What's you version of Tensorflow?

Comment: @abdou_dev TF 2.5

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: I was expecting tensor of tuples, is that possible? Maybe the more general question is it possible to save a list of tuples as tensor?

Comment: Could you please post an example of your expected result?

Comment: As mentioned here , I think that it's bug and it's not fixed yet https://fixexception.com/tensorflow/cannot-iterate-over-a-scalar-tensor/

Comment: Thanks. Maybe to see the problem from different angle, I'm thinking to convert it to ragged tensors instead. Expected output: `tf.RaggedTensor [[], [2, 3], [4]]`. Is that possible?

Comment: I didn't have any idea about `tf.RaggedTensor` , I'm just testing `tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: t elems=a)` and `tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: np.array(t), elems=a)` and it gives me for the first simple result of what you've created and the second it will convert to array ( without any errors )

Comment: did the elements get converted to tuple? Doing this `tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: t elems=a)` will yield no error but it doesn't achieve the main goal which is to convert the element to tuple (just like doing `eval()` on python)

Comment: You didn't give the expected result that you want

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't clear. The general problem is to convert the tensor of strings, `a = tf.Tensor(['()', '(2,3)', '(4)'])` to tensor of tuples (or ragged tensors if that's not possible)

Comment: Please write the expected result not just words